# Dynamically retrieve array from another array and push it to another associative array as key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-push

I'm getting results from an api call.

I'm storing it in an array `$phone_nums`. The structure of array is like this:

Result:

```
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'is_error' => int 0
          'version' => int 3
          'count' => int 3
          'values' => 
            array (size=3)
              0 => 
                array (size=4)
                  "id"            ="1"
                  'contact_id'    = "207"
                  'phone'         = "8888888888"
                  'phone_id_type' = "2"
              1 => 
                array (size=4)

                  "id"            ="2"
                  'contact_id'    = "207"
                  'phone'         = "8475895894"
                  'phone_id_type' = "2"
              2 => 
                array (size=4)
                  "id"            ="2"
                  'contact_id'    = "207"
                  'phone'         = "48948594894"
                  'phone_id_type' = "2"

      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'is_error' => int 0
          'version' => int 3
          'count' => int 1
          'id' => int 160
          'values' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => 
                array (size=4)
                  "id"            ="1"
                  'contact_id'    = "207"
                  'phone'         = "48948594894"
                  'phone_id_type' = "2"
```

Now I have to fetch phone number, ph.no type from this array and add to a new associative array $ph_maps with key being `contact_id` and map corresponding ph numbers to it something like this.

$ph_maps = ("207"=>array(48782387489,4874843899,90483499908), 208=>array(789732187,38983298,938938)

Here is my code. there is some problem with it.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($phone_nums); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < $phone_nums[$i]['count']; $j++) {
        $ph_maps = array();
        $ph_maps[$phone_nums["values"][$i]["contact_id"]] = array($phone_nums[$i]['values'][$j]['phone']);
    }
```

Comment: When saying 'there is some problem with my code', you should specify what the problem is. (current output, error message, ...) It makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: sure.. I'll specific from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You're resetting a new array each time in your loops with `$ph_maps = array();`, erasing the previous entries. You current result is probably an array with a single contact_id / phone entry. Put it outside of the loops.

2 - In your second loop, you're not adding a new entry to your array for each contact_id, but setting a new unique one. You've to add `[]` to force a new entry to be made.

3 - You're adding a new array for each phone number, while in your desired output you seems to simply want the value, so you should remove the `= array(...)`.

4 - You contact_id key wasn't correct : use `$phone_nums[$i]["values"][$j]["contact_id"]` instead of `$phone_nums["values"][$i]["contact_id"]`

```
$ph_maps = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($phone_nums); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < $phone_nums[$i]['count']; $j++) { 
        $ph_maps[$phone_nums[$i]["values"][$j]["contact_id"]][] = $phone_nums[$i]['values'][$j]['phone'];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. You have pin pointed the errors. But using you solution i am not getting $contact _id is keys for the phone numbers. Result is like this                               array (size=1)
  '' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '894503213' (length=9)
      1 => string '849504959' (length=9)
      2 => string '9384738948' (length=10)
      3 => string '9949394920' (length=10)
      4 => string '94494 12094' (length=11)

Comment: Your answer is correct but Instead of keys as 1,2,3 etc i want contact_id. By the by thank you so much

Comment: @ShrinidhiKulkarni Updated my answer, should be ok now.

Comment: @ Clément Malet...Superb. Thank u again.